# Обработать неизвестное кол-во переменных в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, регулярные-выражения

Доброго всем времени суток господа

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?content=$1&category=$2&page=$3&id=$4 [L]
```

Имеется такой вот код в штаксессе. Работает, но есть некоторые непонятки с ним.

```
При адресе скажем http://mysite.ru/1/2/3/4/ - все нормально, но если переменных меньше, то страница выдает ошибку. Подскажите, как написать этот файл, что бы работал в не зависимости от кол-ва переменных?
```

p.s. собственными силами додумался до такого:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?supermassiv=$1 [L,QSA]
```

но, оч. не хочется верить, что это единственное решение, т.к. фактически переменная одна (конечно можно ее разбить, но все же охота несколько переменных)

Comment: Буквально пол часа назад, уже [был вопрос по ЧПУ](http://hashcode.ru/questions/190675/htaccess-%D1%87%D0%BF%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B5). Посмотрите предлагаемое решение. В кратце - все запросы перенаправляются на морду, а вы просто в php разбиваете URI (**$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']**) по слешу и вытаскиваете необходимые данные. Этот способ, на мой взгляд, предпочтителен, т.к. любой недочет в htaccess, приводит к падению сайта

Comment: эмм.. вот еще такое есть (еще ближе к адресу) :

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]

получается, что то, что я спросил реализовать нельзя? только разбираем урл сами? (если так, то прошу коммент в ответ поместить. нет тоже ответ, хоть поиск решения прекращу)

Comment: @mixalef, толи я вас не понимаю, толи вы меня. Я не говорил, что для вашей задачи нет решения. Просто, если вы выбираете такой путь, то вам надо учесть абсолютно все варианты и для каждого прописать правило. Абсолютно все - это значит без исключения, предусмотреть любое кол-во переменных и прочее. Я же вам предлагал, как считаю я и многие другие, вариант универсальный. Не ищите легких путей? - Прописывайте десятки правил.

Comment: Легких путей не искал, не ищу, искать не буду. Хотя бы по тому, что по легкому, я уже сделал. Вот спросил, мож но ли по сложному. Я хочу что бы htaccess понимал только определенное кол-во переменных, в моем случае от 0 до 4х, вот собственно все. Решение сейчас вижу только разбором 1 переменной. По поводу предусмотреть - это уже на страницах сделано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> но, оч. не хочется верить, что это
> единственное решение, т.к. фактически
> переменная одна (конечно можно ее
> разбить, но все же охота несколько
> переменных)

Интуиция вас не подводит - она вам верно указывает что не нужно хотеть верить, что это единственный способ.

Вот эту проблему, которою вы сейчас решаете, принято называть **Механизмом роутера**. К счастью, тысячи PHP-разработчиков сталкивались с подобной проблемой... - и соответсвенно решение есть уже давным давно.

Для того чтобы опять и опять не решать подобные проблемы, существуют написанные библиотеки/классы, которые нужно использовать чтобы экономить время и силы.
Их также принято называть PHP Фрэймворками.

**Вам нужно**:
Просто скачать один из фрэймворков (Cake, Kohana, Symfony, Zend) и посмотреть как работает роутер. Уверяю вас, Вы найдете ответ на то как передавать переменные в не зависимости от их количества.

Также есть просто, классы роутеров (классы отдельно) - в гугл: **PHP routing**.

P.S для использования роутера в `.htaccess`, в 99% случаев вам нужно будет всего лишь только:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]

</ifModule>
```

Comment: т.е. скачать, засунуть на фтп хостинга, и подключить как написали? ок.